# How can I lend a `str` to a thread without copying?

Tags: rust, lifetime

Given

```
fn greet(peeps: &str) {
    println!("Hello, {}", peeps);
}
```

I can do:

```
fn main() {
    let a = "World";
    thread::spawn(move || greet(a)).join().unwrap();
}
```

The compiler understands that the thread does not outlive the borrowed string, but this is merely a special case when the lifetime of the `&str` is known to be `'static`. When I try to do the same with a function argument, it does not compile:

```
fn indirect(peeps: &str) {
    thread::spawn(move || greet(&peeps)).join().unwrap();
    // Does not compile, for fear that the thread may outlive peeps
}
```

However, to a human reader, it is obviously the case that the thread cannot outlive the borrowed string.

I have found two workarounds:

1. Make a copy of the string, which can be moved into the thread:

   ```
   fn indirect(peeps: &str) {
       let peeps = peeps.to_string();
       thread::spawn(move || greet(&peeps)).join().unwrap();
   }
   ```
2. or, make use of the famously deprecated `thread::scoped`:

   ```
   #![feature(scoped)]
   fn indirect_scoped(peeps: &str) {
       thread::scoped(move || greet(&peeps)).join();
   }
   ```

I don't want to specify `'static` lifetime for the function parameter, I'd prefer not to make an unnecessary copy (workaround 1) and I'd prefer not to use deprecated features (workaround 2).

What should I do in this situation?

Comment: It's not clear whether it would suit your use case, but `Arc<String>` could also be a solution to this problem. It would require calling `to_string()` at some point given a `&str`, but then it could be shared across many threads without copying.

Comment: "I'd prefer not to..." -- very understandable. I hope something like `scoped` will come back into the standard library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The approach with `scoped()` is the correct way when you want to pass borrowed data to child threads. While `thread::scoped()` itself is deprecated due to its unsoundness, an alternative sound APIs like [crossbeam](https://github.com/aturon/crossbeam) or [scoped_threadpool](https://github.com/Kimundi/scoped-threadpool-rs) provide a way to do this on stable Rust:

```
extern crate crossbeam;

fn indirect(peeps: &str) {
    crossbeam::scope(|scope| {
        scope.spawn(|| greet(peeps));
    });
}
```